# WordPress : Change footer copyright content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

When i change footer text from gui doesn't change and i can't change it from code manual, am tried to change it from `functions.php` or disable it but i can't.
how to disable or edit footer?
and this footer code

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying the footer
*
* Contains footer content and the closing of the #main and #page div elements.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Kleo
* @since Kleo 1.0
*/
?>
<?php
 /**
 * After main part - action
 */
 do_action('kleo_after_main');
?>
</div><!-- #main -->
    <?php get_sidebar('footer');?>
    <?php 
    /**
     * After footer hook
     * @hooked kleo_go_up
     * @hooked kleo_show_contact_form
     */
    do_action('kleo_after_footer');
    ?>
</div><!-- #page -->
<?php
/**
 * After page hook
 * @hooked kleo_show_side_menu 10
 */
do_action('kleo_after_page');
?>
<!-- Analytics -->
<?php echo sq_option('analytics', ''); ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please mention theme name with demo URL.

Comment: Kleo
http://seventhqueen.com/themes/kleo/home-default/

Answer (score 0):

I found copyright code content in option.php and change it and in footer text and it changed.

Answer (score 0):

you should not edit options.php and you should add the copyright text in WP admin - Theme options.

Cheers